# How to create "ghost-drive" without change the directory?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, cloud

I want to decrease the load from my computer's hard drive and thought of a solution that might be ideal but I do not know if there is a way to implement it.

I would be happy to choose specific paths that will be stored locally on my computer and other paths (especially those that have heavy files and are not frequently used) that will be stored in the cloud or external drive (for that matter, both) so that in case I have an internet connection I can access these paths and when I have no access the web/external drive, I can not access the data.

**Illustration:**

I have a projects folder with about 200 GB of data. Naturally, I only need access on a regular basis to 2/3 projects that weigh no more than 10GB. I would be happy to map the historical materials into a remote drive and have access to it as needed. But I would not want to change all the routings because it would ruin a lot of code snippets I use.

Do you have any idea how to do something like this? Actually, use the directory system in a hybrid way that some of the materials are stored locally and some are stored remotely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some "cloud storage" products (Dropbox Plus, OneDrive) already support this through their custom kernel drivers. They will let you mark certain files folders as "online only", leaving just a placeholder that *looks* like a normal file but occupies no space – the driver will automatically download the data as soon as a program tries to open the placeholder file.